# getting error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')" in React when using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

This is the code that is causing my error:

```js
const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
  async function fetchCars() {
    const response = await axios
      .get("localhost:3001/")
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    if (response) {
      const cs = response.data;
      console.log(cs);
      setCars(cs);
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCars();
  }, []);
```

And these are the errors Im getting in my chrome developer tools console:

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14887:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15828:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20157:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
```

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14887:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15828:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20157:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
```

```
The above error occurred in the <Index> component:

    at Index

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    at throwOnInvalidObjectType (react-dom.development.js:14887:1)
    at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:15828:1)
    at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:19167:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20157:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
```

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:1)
    at Index (App.js:6:1)
    at describeNativeComponentFrame (react-dom.development.js:1092:1)
    at describeFunctionComponentFrame (react-dom.development.js:1187:1)
    at describeFiber (react-dom.development.js:1266:1)
    at getStackByFiberInDevAndProd (react-dom.development.js:1285:1)
    at createCapturedValueAtFiber (react-dom.development.js:18616:1)
    at throwException (react-dom.development.js:19087:1)
    at handleError (react-dom.development.js:26311:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26437:1)
```

I tried using different versions of node and reinstalling my node_modules, I still can't figure out what exactly is causing these errors and how to fix them, because I'm pretty sure I used `useState` correctly.

Comment: Can you show the hole component?

Comment: This is my index.js: https://srcshare.io/63629cba5b718d36ac5ac828

Comment: Could you also post the value of `cs` in your console.log?

Comment: I'm not even getting anything to the console from that for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your code to use a try/catch block like so:

```js
const [cars, setCars] = useState([]);
  async function fetchCars() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("localhost:3001/");
      const cs = response.data;
      console.log(cs);
      setCars(cs);
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(err)
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCars();
  }, []);
```

No guarantee this would work, but I don't think how you have a `.catch` after your `await` statement is "proper".